# Worker on IOS: "This Application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after..."

Tags: ios, multithreading, actionscript-3, air, ios11

I converted my project from Android to IOS through AIR. After stripping out Google Play ANEs and the like, I have been able to successfully test and launch it. In one of my scenes, after user input, the application crashes without warning.

After studying the logs and testing each function triggered, I have determined the Worker (background thread) I made was causing this issue.

When I initialize the worker, after the Worker State is confirmed running in the event handler, I log that the worker is active and have disabled anything else this event would have triggered. The result in the logs states the following:

```
Oct 18 11:07:46 iPhone Mobile Vape Distro(UIKit)[699] <Error>: Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.
Oct 18 11:07:46 iPhone Mobile Vape Distro(Foundation)[699] <Notice>: This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
```

[Full result](https://pastebin.com/sDS4YCNY)

After doing some research, multiple people programming for the iOS specifically triggered this error by triggering some UI function in a background thread they made. However, the only thing that I am initializing in my worker is setting up the command channels and registering [my Cart class](https://github.com/sfxworks/TinyAuthorizeAPI/blob/master/net/sfxworks/tinyauthorizeapi/Cart.as) via registerClassAlias.

Primordial:

```
    private function initAfterCheck():void
    {

        /// Create the background worker
        bgWorker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(BackgroundWorker);

        // Set up the MessageChannels for communication between workers
        bgWorkerCommandChannel = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(bgWorker);
        bgWorker.setSharedProperty("incomingCommandChannel", bgWorkerCommandChannel);

        progressChannel = bgWorker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
        progressChannel.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, handleProgressMessage);
        progressChannel.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_STATE, handleChannelState);
        bgWorker.setSharedProperty("progressChannel", progressChannel);

        resultChannel = bgWorker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
        resultChannel.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, handleResultMessage);
        bgWorker.setSharedProperty("resultChannel", resultChannel);

        // Start the worker
        bgWorker.addEventListener(Event.WORKER_STATE, handleBGWorkerStateChange);
        bgWorker.start();

    }

    private function handleBGWorkerStateChange(e:Event):void 
    {
        log(e.toString());
        log("Worker state = " + bgWorker.state);
        log("Worker to string = " + bgWorker.toString());

        if (bgWorker.state == WorkerState.RUNNING && bgWorkerInitialized == false)
        {

            bgWorkerInitialized = true;
            log("Worker is running.");
            /* Eventual crash (within milliseconds) with other functions beyond here triggering logs before OS officially terminates application.
            dataStore.database.child("stores").child(dataStore.currentStoreID).child("customPrices").once(handleCustomPrices);

            manuScroller = new ScrollContent((this.parent as src.Main).stage, Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
            manuScroller.y = 722;
            manuScroller.spacing = 10;
            manuScroller.velocity = 2;
            addChild(manuScroller);
            itemScroller = new ScrollContent((this.parent as src.Main).stage, Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
            itemScroller.y = 0;
            itemScroller.velocity = 2;
            addChild(itemScroller);
            log("Added scrollers");
            if (dataStore.accountType == AccountType.DRIVER || dataStore.accountType == AccountType.SALES)
            {
                log("Fetching items for truck.");
                dataStore.database.child("truck").child(dataStore.boundTruck).child("items").once(fetchItemsFromTruck);
            }
            else
            {
                selectedTruckItems = new Object();
                dataStore.database.child("manufacturers").once(populateUI);
            }*/
        }
    }
```

Worker:

```
    public function ItemSelectionWorker() 
    {
        trace("Parse worker initialized.");
        init();
    }

    private function init():void 
    {
        registerClassAlias("net.sfxworks.tinyauthorizeapi.Cart", Cart);
        trace("Worker init.");

        commandChannel = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("incomingCommandChannel") as MessageChannel;
        commandChannel.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, handleCommandMessage);

        progressChannel = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("progressChannel") as MessageChannel;
        resultChannel = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("resultChannel") as MessageChannel;
    }
```

That and adobe explicitly states that display objects can't even be processes in a background thread. So I don't see how this could be causing an issue in the first place.

[Worker Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

> Several runtime APIs are not available in code running in a background worker. These primarily consist of APIs related to user input and output mechanisms, or operating system elements like windows and dragging.

**Performance**

Resident memory used: 236.42KB

Malloc memory used: 30.39KB

Disk partition free: 364.11MB

Disk partition used: 11.34GB

Battery level: 100%

Charging state: Unknown

Connection State: Wifi

stay_primary_portraits

**Device**

Model identifier: iPhone 6s (8,1)

Jailbroken Status: Not jailbroken

iOS Version: 11.0.2

Available on disk: 14.89GB

RAM: 1.96GB

Orientation: Face up

Proximity to user: Far

Edit: Additional Information from Firebase Crash Reporting

```
NSInternalInconsistencyException: accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread
1
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess + 1318200
2
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_exception_throw + 34084
3
CoreFoundation
+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 1317896
4
Foundation
-[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 707616
5
UIKit
-[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:] + 2561108
6
UIKit
+[UIWindow _synchronizeDrawingWithPreCommitHandler:] + 2934744
7
UIKit
-[UIInputViewAnimationStyle launchAnimation:afterStarted:completion:forHost:fromCurrentPosition:] + 837376
8
UIKit
-[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 12274212
9
UIKit
__43-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:]_block_invoke.1515 + 12305096
10
UIKit
-[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withTemplateNotificationInfo:] + 12247356
11
UIKit
-[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 12303892
12
UIKit
-[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 12271688
13
UIKit
-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 806744
14
UIKit
7024055864 + 583224
15
UIKit
-[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _reloadInputViewsForResponder:] + 218844
16
UIKit
-[UIWindow _makeKeyWindowIgnoringOldKeyWindow:] + 592104
17
UIKit
-[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenterWindow presentAlertController:animated:completionBlock:] + 12815944
18
UIKit
-[_UIAlertControllerShimPresenter _presentAlertControllerAnimated:completion:] + 12810028
19
UIKit
-[UIAlertView _showAnimated:] + 5417616
20
Mobile Vape Distro
4344427236 + 111332
21
Mobile Vape Distro
4345002328 + 686424
22
Mobile Vape Distro
4345003316 + 687412
23
Mobile Vape Distro
4345031864 + 715960
24
Mobile Vape Distro
4345033468 + 717564
25
Mobile Vape Distro
4345034372 + 718468
26
Mobile Vape Distro
4345059744 + 743840
27
Mobile Vape Distro
4345062428 + 746524
28
Mobile Vape Distro
4348788024 + 4472120
29
Mobile Vape Distro
4348789320 + 4473416
30
Mobile Vape Distro
4350145892 + 5829988
31
Mobile Vape Distro
4348773792 + 4457888
32
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_body + 9000
33
libsystem_pthread.dylib
_pthread_start + 8692
34
libsystem_pthread.dylib
thread_start + 3124
```